# Excel-VBA and xlwings UDF Type Mismatch Error

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings, vba

I'm writing an interface between a sqlite database and excel using python and xlwings. There's one python function:

```
# verifyExcelTickers returns 1, 2, and 3. 2 means everything is alright,
# 1 means the tickerName wasn't found, and 3 means multiple tickers were 
# found.
@xw.func
def verifyExcelTickers (ticker,exchange):
    dbConn = sqlite3.connect("./Python Scripts/Stock_Tracker/stockTracker.db",uri=True)
    return verifyExchTableTicker(ticker,True,exchange,dbConn)[0]
```

that is hassling me. I loaded it into excel using the automatic UDF generator, no issues. If I use the function in the excel spreadsheet, no problem. When I try to get the return value from the function within VBA code, it gives me a type mismatch error

```
' verifyExcelTickers returns integers
Dim result As Integer
result = verifyExcelTickers(tickerName, exchangeName)
If result = 1 Then
    sheet.Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    bFoundError = True
ElseIf result = 2 Then
    sheet.Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ElseIf result = 3 Then
    ' Multiple tickers
    sheet.Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    bFoundError = True
End If
```

The above crashes at the result = ver.... line. If I change the result type to variant, it doesn't complain about it anymore, but if I try to convert to an integer from there, it brings up other errors. Any ideas on what is going on? Been trying to deal with this for a few hours now.

Thanks

Comment: If you use a `Variant` for `result`, what value does `result` contain after the line executes?  And what `Variant` subtype has it been set to (`Variant/Integer`, `Variant/Long`, `Variant/Double`, etc, etc)?  Use the Locals window to see what it is doing.

Comment: I didn't know about the locals window at all. I checked it out, and it's a Variant/Variant(0 to 0, 0 to 0). I changed the later lines of code to access it through result(0,0) and it works as intended now.